# Masterpage not recognising Checklist in Content (child) page

Tags: vb.net

Apologies as this has most likely been asked and answered but I can't seem to find the right search term!

I have a master page (master.vb) which should see the checklist on button press but instead can not see it. I've looked as ctl001 etc..

Issue: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'MainContent_CheckBoxList1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

contentpage.aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Master Page

```
For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            If item.Selected Then
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
```

The issue is with "CheckBoxList1.Items" not being recognised. I've not quite sure where to go now. The code checks if one Checkbox or more has been ticked.

I know the pages are linked correctly as it displays correctly if I remove the checklist reference in the MasterPage.

Comment: So I managed to solve it with.. Dim yourCheckBoxList As CheckBoxList = DirectCast(MainContent.FindControl("CheckBoxList1"), CheckBoxList)
Dim selectedCount As Integer = yourCheckBoxList.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Count(Function(li) li.Selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim yourCheckBoxList As CheckBoxList = DirectCast(MainContent.FindControl("CheckBoxList1"), CheckBoxList) Dim selectedCount As Integer = yourCheckBoxList.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Count(Function(li) li.Selected)
```